# I cant upload df to my google disk with google API

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, file-upload

```
input:
spreadsheet_name = 'spreadsheet_name'
sheet = 'spreadsheet_name'
d2g.upload(y_df, spreadsheet_name, sheet, credentials=credentials)

output:
IncorrectCellLabel: (1, 0)
```

```
`or input:
path_to_credentials = #my json file

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path_to_credentials, scopes)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)


spreadsheet_name = 'spreadsheet_name'
try:
    sh = gc.open(spreadsheet_name)
except gspread.SpreadsheetNotFound:
    sh = gc.create(spreadsheet_name)
    
worksheet_name = 'spreadsheet_name'
try:
    worksheet = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name)
except gspread.WorksheetNotFound:
    worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title=worksheet_name, rows="100", cols="20")


set_with_dataframe(worksheet, y_df)`
```

it gives same output.

I made this sheets on my google disk:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyROn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfPsn.png)

I expect uploading df to my google sheets.

Comment: Have you tried this for instance: `set_with_dataframe(worksheet, y_df, row = 1, col = 1)`, and see if you'll still get the same output?